# KendoUI Upload widget template

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to customize the HTML used by a `kendoUpload` widget, but I can't get it to work.

I've followed the demo on their website, read the documentation, but I'm still getting the default template (aka, my custom template is not getting applied whatsoever).

The Javascript and the template:

```
$("#files").kendoUpload({
            async: {
                saveUrl: Configuration.BaseUrl + "/portaluserquote/SourceFileUpload",
                removeUrl: Configuration.BaseUrl + "/portaluserquote/RemoveSourceFileUpload",
                autoUpload: true
            },
            template:"<span class='k-progress'></span>"+
                "<div class='file-wrapper'>"+
                    "<span class='file-icon #=addExtensionClass(files[0].extension)#'></span>"+
                    "<h4 class='file-heading file-name-heading'>Name: #=name#</h4>"+
                    "<h4 class='file-heading file-size-heading'>Size: #=size# bytes</h4>"+
                    "<button type='button' class='k-upload-action'></button>"+
                "</div>",
            
            multiple: true
            
        });
```

A screenshot with the generated DOM:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the kendo version. As soon as I updated to the latest, the templating for kendoUpload worked.

I believe this feature was added later..

Comment: What version were you running and which did you upgrade to?

Comment: I had a similar problem, I updated from 2013.1.319 to 2013.2.716.  I also went as far as adding a reference to Kendo.MVC.dll to my Visual Studio 2012 project to enable Razor markup,t his fixed my issue.  Additionally I added kendo.all.min.intellisense.js.

Answer (score 1):

You put directly the HTML instead of invoking `kendo.template` with it. According the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/upload#configuration-template) it should be a template. :

```
$("#files").kendoUpload({
    async: {
        saveUrl: Configuration.BaseUrl + "/portaluserquote/SourceFileUpload",
        removeUrl: Configuration.BaseUrl + "/portaluserquote/RemoveSourceFileUpload",
        autoUpload: true
    },
    template:kendo.template("<span class='k-progress'></span>"+
        "<div class='file-wrapper'>"+
            "<span class='file-icon #=addExtensionClass(files[0].extension)#'></span>"+
            "<h4 class='file-heading file-name-heading'>Name: #=name#</h4>"+
            "<h4 class='file-heading file-size-heading'>Size: #=size# bytes</h4>"+
            "<button type='button' class='k-upload-action'></button>"+
        "</div>"),
    multiple: true
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input. I've tried this multiple times but it didn't work. Turned out it was a different issue.